# Getting error with addEventListener for my popup form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a form that pops up when a button is clicked. I have positioned it and styled it but my script doesn't seem to be working. I have checked the id's and they match and have also checked the class name and there is no issue. I can't seem to locate where my script went wrong. I apologies for the large amount of code but I wasn't sure if there is anything I didn't need to include. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the code

```js
document.querySelector("#new_record_submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".popup").classList.add("active");
});

document.querySelector(".popup .close-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".popup").classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  right: 35%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.25);
  transition: top 0ms ease-in-out 200ms, opacity 200ms ease-in-out 0ms, transform 20ms ease-in-out 0ms;
pointer-events: none
}

.popup.active {
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.25);
  transition: top 0ms ease-in-out 0ms, opacity 200ms ease-in-out 0ms, transform 20ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #16a583;
  color: #232322;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="new_record"><a href="">New Record</a><img class="new_record_icon" src="./images/new_record.png"></button>

<div class="popup">
  <div class="close-btn">
    &times;
  </div>
  <h2>Add a Customer</h2>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <form method="post" action="customers.php">
    <label>Customers Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="customer_name" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Customers Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="customer_address" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Customers Phone number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="customer_phone" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Customers Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="customer_email" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button class="new_record_submit" type="submit" id="new_record_submit" name="submit_customers"><p>Submit</p></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work? The button that makes the popup visible is inside the popup. Is the first click listener supposed to be on `#new_record`?

Comment: Yes, I changed it now. Can't believe i missed that. It still doesn't work but that was definitely one of the problems

Comment: instead of using `opacity:0` use `display: hidden` to hide and unhide "active" elements?

Comment: I have an error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener'). Does this mean my code has a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.popup` element has an opacity of 0, but is still covering the button, so you can't click through it.

A simple way to fix this: give the `.popup` a `pointer-events: none` You could also give it a `display: none`, but then you wouldn't have the fading animation.

Also, as @Barmar said, the button you are adding an event listener to show the popup is actually inside the popup. Give the button at the top an id of `new_record` and add the click event listener to that one instead.

Comment: I added ```pointer-events: none``` to ```.popup``` and changed the id to the correct button but it still has an same error of 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')'

Comment: Can you show your new code?

Comment: sure ill update it now

Answer (score 0):

there is a little typo in your code in `document.querySelector("#new_record_submit")`, should be `document.querySelector("#new_record")`,
because `<button class="new_record"><a href="">New Record</a><img class="new_record_icon" src="./images/new_record.png"></button>` ,

and also you can use `clasList.toogle()` to clicked

```js
document.querySelector(".new_record").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector(".popup").classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  right: 35%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.25);
  transition: top 0ms ease-in-out 200ms, opacity 200ms ease-in-out 0ms, transform 20ms ease-in-out 0ms;
pointer-events: none
}

.popup.active {
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.25);
  transition: top 0ms ease-in-out 0ms, opacity 200ms ease-in-out 0ms, transform 20ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #16a583;
  color: #232322;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="new_record"><a href="">New Record</a><img class="new_record_icon" src="./images/new_record.png"></button>

<div class="popup">
  <div class="close-btn">
    &times;
  </div>
  <h2>Add a Customer</h2>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <form method="post" action="customers.php">
    <label>Customers Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="customer_name" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Customers Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="customer_address" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Customers Phone number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="customer_phone" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Customers Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="customer_email" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button class="new_record_submit" type="submit" id="new_record_submit" name="submit_customers"><p>Submit</p></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great in JS fiddle but doesn't seem to work on my webpage, does this mean there is an issue with my webpage?

Comment: what error did you get?